# How to UPDATE a column using a variable?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

I have two questions:

1) How can I call a variable inside the UPDATE Query because i want to use the same line to update lots of columns.
I did it in the INSERT and SELECT, but it cause error in UPDATE
What i used where:

```
string x="term";
 try{

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ourproject?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&user=luffy&password=111111");
    Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();
    String select = "SELECT ('" + x  + "') FROM test WHERE doc=0"; 
    stmt.executeUpdate(select);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();   
   }
```

2) if i could call a variable, how can I update its value by adding 1?
i tried this and it worked:

```
try{

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ourproject?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&user=luffy&password=111111");
    Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();
    String update = "UPDATE test SET term=term+1 WHERE doc=0"; 
    PreparedStatement updateQuey =con.prepareStatement(update);
    updateQuery.executeUpdate(update);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();   
   }
```

But i need to call X , because i want to use the same line for more than one column.
thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use prepared statements with parameters. [here is the docu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) from oracle about it.

in your context:

```
String update = "UPDATE test SET term = ? WHERE doc=0"; 
PreparedStatement updateQuey = con.prepareStatement(update);
updateQuey.setInt(1, x);
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

BTW: i don't think you need the update string as parameter of `executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

if you are specific about statement then

```
 String update = "UPDATE test SET term=" + yourVariable + " WHERE doc=0";
```

But always prefer prepared statement over statement to avoid sql injection which makes your application/software more reliable and less vulnerable. For prepare statement refer answer posted by luksch